# Repo sync hangs on platform/hardware/ti/am57x

Tags: android, git, android-source, repo, android-automotive

Trying to build Android Automotive OS from source for Pixel 4 XL, as per instructions at:
https://source.android.com/devices/automotive/start/pixelxl#code-sync-and-build

Trying this on a MacOS Big Sur 11.2;

Using the following call:
`repo sync -j8 -c -v`
(8 job-threads, checkout, verbose)

It will always hang on `Checking out: 38% (288/748) platform/hardware/ti/am57x`
I know it hangs, as the CPU usage of `git-remote-https` has dropped from 99% (8 times) to zero.

I've tried (without success) to fix the specific repository using the following method:

```
$ cd platform/hardware/ti/am57x
$ git status
Not currently on any branch.
nothing to commit, working tree clean
$ git branch -r
  m/android-10.0.0_r40 -> tags/android-10.0.0_r40
$ git checkout -b android-10.0.0_r40 m/android-10.0.0_r40
Switched to a new branch 'android-10.0.0_r40'
```

I was pretty sure this would fix the problem, but the next `repo sync` hangs at the same place, and gives the following message:
`hardware/ti/am57x/: leaving android-10.0.0_r40; does not track upstream`

Any help is welcome.

Comment: `git-remote-https` should eventually stop doing anything because the repository/ies will be fully copied locally. The *checkout* process just needs any given repository to exist; it should not hang, because it can't even start until the repository is complete, and all it does is *extract the archived files from some commit* (and set Git up to know which commit that is). If the "extract the archived files" step appears to hang, that usually indicates a hardware problem with the computer, although it needs more diagnosing.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks! For now I'm trying to do the sync without the -c flag; See if that helps.